# Синхронный запрос в ajax в отдельной функцие?

Tags: javascript

### // Функция загружает требуемый XML файл в синхронном режиме

```
function loadXML(url){
    var reqMessage = getXmlHttpRequest();
    reqMessage.open("GET", url, false);
    reqMessage.send(null);

    return reqMessage.responseXML;
}
```

Она работает только в консоле весит предупреждение :

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its      detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check

Надо делать в место этого так

```
Вот так делать не надо:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/query", /*async*/ false); // async=false
xhr.send(null);
if (xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
Вместо этого следует использовать колбэки:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/query"); // async=true
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

### Подскажите пожалуйста, как переписать первую функцию что бы она загружала файл и остальной скрипт ждал пока эта функция не вернет результат?

Comment: `и остальной скрипт ждал` - Ждать будет весь браузер - javascript однопоточный. Освойте ассинхронные методы.

Comment: Есть ещё `async/await` из черновика ES2017.

Comment: так у меня эта функция вложена в другой ajax запрос ( асинхронный )